# Cannot find module 'webpack-manifest-plugin' (beginner)

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, webpack

I am trying to make my WordPress workflow automated using node and npm.
node and npm are installed correctly. However as soon as I run the command `npm run devFast`
I received and error which states that:

```
\[webpack-cli\] Failed to load 'C:\\Users\\bilal\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\5.1 21-end\\fictional-university-theme\\webpack.config.js' config
\[webpack-cli\] Error: Cannot find module 'webpack-manifest-plugin'  
Require stack:

- C:\\Users\\bilal\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\5.1 21-end\\fictional-university-theme\\webpack.config.js
- C:\\Users\\bilal\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\5.1 21-end\\fictional-university-theme\\node_modules\\webpack-cli\\lib\\webpack-cli.js
- C:\\Users\\bilal\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\5.1 21-end\\fictional-university-theme\\node_modules\\webpack-cli\\lib\\bootstrap.js
- C:\\Users\\bilal\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\5.1 21-end\\fictional-university-theme\\node_modules\\webpack-cli\\bin\\cli.js
- C:\\Users\\bilal\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\5.1 21-end\\fictional-university-theme\\node_modules\\webpack\\bin\\webpack.js
  at Module.\_resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)
  at Module.\_load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)  
  at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)  
  at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
  at Object.\<anonymous\> (C:\\Users\\bilal\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\5.1 21-end\\fictional-university-theme\\webpack.config.js:15:24)
  at Module.\_compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)  
  at Module.\_extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
  at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)  
  at Module.\_load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)  
  at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19) {  
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: \[
  'C:\\Users\\bilal\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\5.1 21-end\\fictional-university-theme\\webpack.config.js'
```

Here is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "fictional-university-theme",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "wp-scripts build",
    "start": "wp-scripts start",
    "dev": "wp-scripts start",
    "devFast": "wp-scripts start",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@glidejs/glide": "^3.4.1",
    "@wordpress/scripts": "*",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^5.88.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4"
  }
}
```

and here is my webpack.config.js

```
const currentTask = process.env.npm_lifecycle_event
const path = require("path")
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin")
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin")
const ManifestPlugin = require("webpack-manifest-plugin")
const fse = require("fs-extra")

const postCSSPlugins = [require("postcss-import"), require("postcss-mixins"), require("postcss-simple-vars"), require("postcss-nested"), require("postcss-hexrgba"), require("postcss-color-function"), require("autoprefixer")]

class RunAfterCompile {
  apply(compiler) {
    compiler.hooks.done.tap("Update functions.php", function () {
      // update functions php here
      const manifest = fse.readJsonSync("./bundled-assets/manifest.json")

      fse.readFile("./functions.php", "utf8", function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err)
        }

        const scriptsRegEx = new RegExp("/bundled-assets/scripts.+?'", "g")
        const vendorsRegEx = new RegExp("/bundled-assets/vendors.+?'", "g")
        const cssRegEx = new RegExp("/bundled-assets/styles.+?'", "g")

        let result = data.replace(scriptsRegEx, `/bundled-assets/${manifest["scripts.js"]}'`).replace(vendorsRegEx, `/bundled-assets/${manifest["vendors~scripts.js"]}'`).replace(cssRegEx, `/bundled-assets/${manifest["scripts.css"]}'`)

        fse.writeFile("./functions.php", result, "utf8", function (err) {
          if (err) return console.log(err)
        })
      })
    })
  }
}

let cssConfig = {
  test: /\.css$/i,
  use: ["css-loader?url=false", { loader: "postcss-loader", options: { plugins: postCSSPlugins } }]
}

let config = {
  entry: {
    scripts: "./js/scripts.js"
  },
  plugins: [],
  module: {
    rules: [
      cssConfig,
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ["@babel/preset-react", ["@babel/preset-env", { targets: { node: "12" } }]]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

if (currentTask == "devFast") {
  config.devtool = "source-map"
  cssConfig.use.unshift("style-loader")
  config.output = {
    filename: "bundled.js",
    publicPath: "http://localhost:3000/"
  }
  config.devServer = {
    before: function (app, server) {
            server._watch(["./**/*.php", "!./functions.php"])
    },
    public: "http://localhost:3000",
    publicPath: "http://localhost:3000/",
    disableHostCheck: true,
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname),
    contentBasePublicPath: "http://localhost:3000/",
    hot: true,
    port: 3000,
    headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
    }
  }
  config.mode = "development"
}

if (currentTask == "build" || currentTask == "buildWatch") {
  cssConfig.use.unshift(MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader)
  postCSSPlugins.push(require("cssnano"))
  config.output = {
    publicPath: "/wp-content/themes/fictional-university-theme/bundled-assets/",
    filename: "[name].[chunkhash].js",
    chunkFilename: "[name].[chunkhash].js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "bundled-assets")
  }
  config.mode = "production"
  config.optimization = {
    splitChunks: { chunks: "all" }
  }
  config.plugins.push(new CleanWebpackPlugin(), new MiniCssExtractPlugin({ filename: "styles.[chunkhash].css" }), new ManifestPlugin({ publicPath: "" }), new RunAfterCompile())
}

module.exports = config
```

I am learning WordPress development and I am not aware of node and npm.
I have tried manually linking webpack to npm through `npm link webpack`

it threw me the following error

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\\Users\\bilal\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\webpack
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe /d /s /c husky install
npm ERR! 'husky' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
npm ERR! operable program or batch file.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\\Users\\bilal\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache_logs\\2023-08-01T03_52_58_977Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: Then try to install the missing dependencies.

Comment: FYI, I removed the PHP and Wordpress tags since the question/issue is unrelated to those.

Comment: @LinDu have installed the missing dependencies but the problem still persist

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm. Two things here.

To resolve the 'Cannot find module' error, you need to install the missing 'webpack-manifest-plugin' using the command:

```
npm install --save-dev webpack-manifest-plugin
```

But bear in mind, 'webpack-manifest-plugin' is deprecated and incorporated into 'webpack' itself from version '5'. As you're using 'webpack' version '5.88.2', you might want to check the official 'webpack' documentation if you encounter any issues.

The 'husky' error is not related to your 'webpack' issue. You can ignore it if 'husky' is not necessary for your project. If needed, install it with:

```
npm install husky --save-dev
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Just a note, I don't believe `webpack-manifest-plugin` is deprecated. It's the only method I could find in the webpack docs to extract the manifest into json. https://webpack.js.org/guides/output-management/#the-manifest